# Pros and cons of using a ratio vs a difference score to compare group means

Tags: statistical-significance, normality-assumption, ratio

I plan to collect data from 2 groups of people (Gp_1 and Gp_2), some few hundred people in all. Each person will respond to 100 yes/no tasks, each response yielding both accuracy and reaction time data.  Each person will respond to two types of stimuli (Stim_1 and Stim_2), 50 yes/no tasks for each type of stimulus.

I would like to compare the groups on both accuracy and reaction time.  My primary research hypothesis is that Gp_1 will respond more accurately than Gp_2 to Stim_2. A secondary research hypothesis that there will be no between group difference in accuracy for Stim_1.  I do not have a prediction as to the reaction times of the two groups to the two stimuli (neither for means or for variance).

I plan to compute the mean accuracy and mean reaction time for each person to the two types of stimuli.  After that, there seem to be at least two options: (1) get difference scores for each person for accuracy and for time to respond for the two types of stimuli, or (2) form a ratio for each person for accuracy and for time to respond for each of the two types of stimuli.  Perhaps there are other options.  I plan to conduct statistical tests.

How might the power of the two data analysis approaches compare?  Or what conditions should I consider to compare power?

Should I expect one of the two statistics above to better conform to the assumptions of a parametric test of statistical significance?

Are there other approaches I should be considering for comparing the two groups on their performance on the two types of stimuli?

This question is similar, but has no answer: [Ratio measure vs. difference measure?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/366611/ratio-measure-vs-difference-measure)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the absolute values of scores need to be taken into account. Given a difference score of common magnitude, the ratio will be closer to one when the absolute values of the raw scores are larger rather than smaller. The difference score is thus less dependent on absolute magnitude. Note that this choose (difference scores vs. ratios) also has the potential to change the overall ranking of subjects.

The chief benefit of ratios appears to be that it produces a common scale against which to compare different metrics. Of course, the same thing might be achieved using a transformation (e.g., z scores), but ratios have a somewhat more intuitive interpretation.

If using ratios, considering using a log10 transform of the ratio data - this will produce values that are symmetrical around zero and can assess more easily for treatment effects in both directions depending on follow-up analyses.